# What system table contains filegroup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to get statistics about my databases and can't seem to find out where to get the FileGroup from any of the system tables.

I'm selecting from sysfiles to get the filename, but I'd like to know the actual filegroup as well.  I can see the filegroup by using sp_helpfile, but I was wondering if anyone knows what system table I can use to get it?

I'd like to join to sysfiles to include some of the data available there.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Uh, did you try [`sys.filegroups`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187782.aspx) and [`sys.database_files`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx)? Stop using `sysfiles` (or `sysfilegroups`, @PashaPash). Please [read the warnings in the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178009.aspx).

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks Aaron, we've been trying to update our code to be prepared for future versions of SQL Server but definitely missed this one.